# In Objective-C, what naming convention shows that a property is private?

Tags: objective-c, properties, naming-conventions

There appears to be no good or consistent convention for this.

If a class's properties are declared within the anonymous class extension of a class in the @implementation section of a .m file, they are essentially private.

However, when looking at all properties in the class, there is no way I can tell by looking at a property if it is a private property or not.

This is less than good.

Is there some naming convention that exists that makes good sense here?

Comment: what you can do is do your own naming convention. Like add a suffix p_variableName for private properties, and public ones, without suffix.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there is a naming convention for distinguishing between public and private properties in `objc`.

You can always copy the property, look in the .h file and if that property is there it's public. otherwise, it's probably not.

Comment: Yeah, my goal is to look at the property and instantly know if it is public or private because anything else is a waste of time.

Comment: Yeah, I hear you with wanting to save time. In your case, you might want to come up with your own naming convention, given that it's probably a waste of time trying to find a commonly used naming convention for this case. edit: didn't read @GeneCode said. But yes, what they said :)

Comment: Yup.  I wanted to refer to the wisdom of the crowd before I just started plopping p in front of everything.  Some people reserve p for protected, but honestly, we need a convention for private a metric ton more than for protected.